# Carrierwave. image field displaying as #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f51c0d88a88> instead of image name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have 6 image fields in a model. (img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6)
When I upload images to all these 6 fields and then display their values they all show the uploaded image name. Except for img6 field. This is what it is showing:-

```
ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f51c0d88a88
```

I have checked all fields they are strings.

Can anyone please let me know what can be the possible cause? Here is the form:-

```
<%= form_for(@product, :html => { :multipart => true }, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <div id="addImages">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <%= label :image1, "Main image" %>
            <%= f.file_field :img1 %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <%= label :image2, "2nd image" %> (Optional)  
            <%= f.file_field :img2 %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <%= label :image3, "3rd image" %> (Optional)  
            <%= f.file_field :img3 %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <%= label :image4, "4th image" %> (Optional)  
            <%= f.file_field :img4 %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <%= label :image5, "5th image" %> (Optional)  
            <%= f.file_field :img5 %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <%= label :image6, "6th image" %> (Optional)  
            <%= f.file_field :img6 %>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-default btn-lg" do %><b>Submit Product</b><% end %>
    </div>
```

One thing I forgot to tell. img6 field was previously thumbnail. I renamed this column to img6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry. Forgot to add this to model

mount_uploader :img6, ProductUploader

my bad

Comment: Nothing to say sorry for, it's helpful to others.